# Why does an egg on the bottom of a pot filled with spinning water rise to the top?

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

If you start stirring water contained in a cylinder shape container a vortex will form and it will pull objects to the top. 
Why does a vortex even form in such a way that the center gets deeper than the boundary? 
I guess the object is pulled up cause water is spinning faster the higher up it is because of viscosity.

If you are going to use math , ( vector calculus fluid dynamics of something, do NOT USE COORDINATES in your explanation..

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you have against coordinates?

Comment: The comment box is too small ..

Comment: Let's not get of topic here

Comment: *"Let's not get of topic here"* It's not off topic. You can't do meaningful math in physics without a reference frame.

Comment: This is not a meaningful sentence. A reference frame is not coordinates.

Comment: Also the point of the question is conceptual understanding , if you can supplement it with meaningful math that's great.

Comment: Coordinates will do no good explaining anything..

Comment: @LeoKovacic Coordinate-free explanations will only get you so far. At a certain point, in order to apply a coordinate-free solution to an actual physical situation, you nearly always have to choose some set of coordinates.

Comment: If you can't understand basics of mathematical physics just try and answer it only conceptually  , it's just an everyday physics problem it's not string theory. Math is optional..

Comment: Chiming in on whether or not to use math, and whether or not to use coordinate systems: I take it as obvious that *conceptual discussion* of this case does not require mention of any coordinate system; it doesn't even require mathematical expression. The elements that go into the explanation are readily encountered in daily life, such as: to sustain circumnavigating motion a centripetal force must be provided.

Comment: @LeoKovacic, I suspect that people here are reacting more to your ALL CAPS COMMANDMENT than, to the question of whether or not a specific coordinate system is needed in order to adequately express some physical law.

Comment: Let it go , just answer the question if you know, or the subquestion, why dooes the water itself rise along the edges and the depression is created in the center of spinning water..

Answer (score 1):

I think your observation is related to the observation that if you have a (cilindrical) glass with water and tea leaves resting on the bottom, then gentle stirring will tend to gather the tea leaves at the center of the bottom.

Here 'gentle stirring' is meant to convey that you want the rotating fluid to be as close as possible to [solid body rotation](http://weathertank.mit.edu/links/projects/solid-body-rotation-introduction/solid-body-rotation-how-to)

You can get actual solid body rotation when the container is itself co-rotating with the rotating fluid. In the case you are asking about the glass is not co-rotating, so the fluid layer that is in contact with the wall is slowed down due to friction.

In the case of solid body rotation every single part of the fluid is experiencing the amount of centripetal force that is required to sustain circumnavigating motion at that angular velocity.

But with the layers of fluid close to the wall slowed down the fluid level (close to the wall) cannot climb up enough to provide sufficient centripetal force. So: the top layer flows towards the outside. This pushes the fluid layer that is close to the wall down. This downward motion pushes the central columnn up.

Apparently the eggs you are using are only barely non-buoyant. Apparently the upward flow of the central column is sufficient to lift the eggs up from the bottom of the container.